# Heap vs Stack Storage

Tags: cpu, heap-memory, ram, stack-memory

I have some confusion about where the actual data and addresses are stored on the computer itself. I can't seem to find any information about it. I'm guessing that the heap is on the RAM because it is a pool of memory and the stack lives in the CPU registry.

Am I completely wrong or somewhat correct?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Both Stack and Heap are stored in RAM.
Without me having to go on, see this thread for a very useful discussion/explanation on this topic:  [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)